# How to subtract count of two columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wanting to get the difference of count value of two columns in same table so far i come up with this code

```
select (select count( user_id)
        from weekly_customer_RFM_TABLE
        where SEGMENT = 'champion'
          and SEGMENTED_DATE = '2022-10-14'
            -
                               (select
                                    count( user_id)
                                    from weekly_customer_RFM_TABLE
                                    where SEGMENT = 'champion'
                                    and SEGMENTED_DATE = '2022-10-07')) as total_changes
```

i am getting result  0 here but the original result will be  45
I cannot figure out what i am missing here. Please help me to solve the problem. Those data are in same table but   filter by segment and dates

Comment: Your query is correct. Check the 2 select counts separately and see what they return.

Comment: No, it isn't. You can create a fiddle and try out. Assuming the first select will return 2 and the second one 1, the result will be 0 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here with a single pass over the `weekly_customer_RFM_TABLE` table:

```
SELECT SUM(SEGMENTED_DATE = '2022-10-14') -
       SUM(SEGMENTED_DATE = '2022-10-07') AS total_changes
FROM weekly_customer_RFM_TABLE
WHERE SEGMENT = 'champion';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use it in a case statement for different segment filters? My main goal is to make a summary table of changes

Comment: If you are asking something fairly different, then I suggest opening a new question.  Yes, you may replace my calls to `SUM()` with `CASE` expressions, e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN SEGMENTED_DATE = '2022-10-14' THEN user_id END)`